# Check if webpage contains text

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am getting a webpage using `file_get_contents();`:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

How do I check if the webpage contains the text 'hello' or 'bye'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$exists = (strpos($file, 'hello') !== false) || (strpos($file, 'bye') !== false);
if ($exists !== false) {
    print 'Found';
}
```

Comment: sorry, does this check to see if hello is there or bye?

Comment: yes it does check to see if hello is there or bye

Comment: no i mean which one does it check for

Comment: @bobjomes Look at the code, have a guess! If you cannot work this out then maybe you need to find another career or hobby

Comment: @bobjomes it checks for both, if either hello or bye is found `Found` will get printed

Comment: @user3360140 Actually its not fool proof as it stands, maybe if you read this you can work out a better solution ___Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.___

Comment: Thats better so +1

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
if (strpos($file, 'hello') !== false)
{
    echo "Exist..";
}
```

Comment: sorry, does this check to see if hello is there or bye?